# Linq-to-entity subqueries with async

Tags: async-await, linq-to-entities

I have an async method which generates a query where I'm doing something like this:

```cs
var query = context.table.AsNoTracking()
    .Where(whereQuery)
    .GroupJoin(...)
    .GroupJoin(... (a, b) => new Lab {
       foo = a.bar
    }
)
```

If it's just that, I can do an `await query.ToArrayAsync()` and all is good.  What I'm running into now is that I then need to do a subquery:

```cs
var query = context.table.AsNoTracking()
    .Where(whereQuery)
    .GroupJoin(...)
    .GroupJoin(... (a, b) => new Lab {
       foo = a.bar,
       bar = (
           from x in ... select new { ... }
       )
    }
)
```

That `bar` element is multiple items being returned, and so it can't just be done as part of a join.  As soon as I do that, I now don't know how I can make that inner query be awaitable.  What's the right syntax to use for that?

The main "outer" query is done as method calls because I'm passing an `Expression` to the method for the `whereQuery` but sometimes those "inner" queries will be done either way.

So I'm ending up with something like:

```
[
  {
     "foo": 17,
     "bar": [
         { "a": 12 },
         { "b": 73 }
     ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Why does * can't just be done as part of a join* because of *completely separate tables*? Are they on the same context?

Comment: The completely separate tables is less important.  The more important part is that it's multiple rows being returned.  I updated the question to provide more clarity.

Comment: You can still use joins and groups. I still don't understand the question. You write the query and you iterate it. It's the iteration part that can be asynchronous, not the query itself.

Comment: @PauloMorgado Sound like I'm just worried about nothing then?  In the example I show above, when I do my `await query.ToArrayAsync()` then both the inner and outer queries will be asynchronously dealt with?

Comment: There's only one query!